# Browser try to render images before ng-repeat processed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple case: some objects output via ng-repeat to html page. Every object has a path to image to show. Here's the problem: even though I have an empty array of objects, it seems like the browser tries to load image with incorrect URL (I see 404 errors via firebug). Code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="item in searchItems" ng-if="$index%2==0">
    <div class="span5" ng-repeat="item in searchItems|limitTo:2:$index">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="border-style:none;box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;">
        <b>{{item.name}}</b><br>
        <img height="160" src="{{item.imageUrl}}" class="img-rounded"><br>
      </div><!--thumbnail-->
    </div><!--span-->
  </div>
</ul>
```

Error that I see in firebug:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/app/%7B%7Bitem.imageUrl%7D%7D

So it seems like the browser tries to load image before angularjs processes its instructions. Besides this error, everything is working well. However, I want to eliminate this problem. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-src`. It's the angular.js solution to this problem. `ng-src` prevents your browser from "jumping the gun", an only loads the image once the `item.imageUrl`'s value has been properly resolved.

To quote the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) on ng-src:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

So, your code would become:

```
<img height="160" ng-src="{{item.imageUrl}}" class="img-rounded"><br>
```